# How can I create names of dict's from a sequense of tuples of strings?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have:  `paare = {('F1', 'F2'), ('F2', 'F3'), ...}` and want create a list of dict's like:

`[F1F2 = dict(a='F1', b='F2'), F2F3 = dict(a='F2', b='F3'), ...]` nothing must be sorted;

```
for k, v in paare: => ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) [that's not my main question]
```

When I compose the name of the dict's like dnam = 'F1F2' and then try to use this
composed string "dnam" to define a new dict like pnam = {} then it is called 'pnam' and not 'F1F2'.

Is there a nice way to solve the problem?

Comment: The order in which values in *paare* are observed may not be as you'd expect. This is because you're declaring a set. You say "nothing must be sorted". Well, that's easy - just don't sort anything but bear in mind the peculiarity of sets in terms of order. The intention behind your stated output requirement makes no sense as that's not a Python construct

Comment: Thank you!!! It's really a set, not a didt: I should better know, what I do.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dict comprehension like so (you can't have a key value mapping with a list):

```
>>> paare = {('F1', 'F2'), ('F2', 'F3')}
>>> pnam = {f'{a}{b}': {'a': a, 'b': b} for a, b in paare}
>>> pnam
{'F1F2': {'a': 'F1', 'b': 'F2'}, 'F2F3': {'a': 'F2', 'b': 'F3'}}
```

Comment: I tried this dict comprehension but got ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2).  Can a string be the name of a dict? Or has it typed in via keyboard? Meanwhile I declared "paare" as dict with key:value items like 'F1F2': {} and filled in later the results of my programm. Nevertheless i'm very greatful about your hints: I have learnd much from them!!!

Comment: Try copy-pasting instead of manually typing. Should work unless you are using Python 2/ Python <3.6